# replace null values in string type column with zero PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, replace, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null

I need to replace null values in string type columns to be 0.
Data looks like this:

```
df.groupBy('content').count().show() 
+---------------+------+
|        content| count|
+---------------+------+
|         videos|   754|
|      food-news| 76151|
|           null|    39|
|             uk| 23879|
```

I have tried this:

```
df.na.fill(0).show()
```

But this piece of code only takes care of int type columns. How can I replace it for string type columns?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill with a string '0' too:

```
df = df.na.fill(0).na.fill('0')
```

Comment: After applying your peice of code, I ran ```df.groupBy('my_column').count().show()``` I still see `null` in the list...

Comment: @Chique_Code Did you do `df = df.na.fill('0')`? Simply doing `df.na.fill('0')` wil not modify `df`. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ah! That did the trick. Sorry about that. I have accepted and upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In below code all int values will be replaced by 0 and string values to ' '(blank).

```
df = df.na.fill(0).na.fill(' ')
```